# Mostrar Div apenas no segundo pageview e eliminar o cookie em um determinado tempo

Tags: javascript, cookies

Já procurei e não achei nada relacionado, queria um código para mostrar uma DIV no segundo pageview de uma pessoa em um site, e não mostrar mais num periodo pré determinado.

Answer (score 1):

Pode criar um cookie com a data atual e depois procurar esse cookie. Na segunda visualização junta mais uma variavel ao cookie para saber que já foi visto.

Por exemplo:

```
// gerar um timestamp em milisegundos
var agora = Date.now(); // ou "new Date().getTime();" em browsers antigos

// ler a data do cookie, se houver
var dataCookie = document.cookie.match(/_criado=([\d]+)/);
dataCookie = dataCookie ? parseInt(dataCookie[0], 10) : agora;

// procurar no cookie por "_criado"
if (document.cookie.indexOf('_criado' == -1)){
    // primeira visita: criar o cookie
    document.cookie = document.cookie + '; _criado=' + agora + ';';
}
else if (document.cookie.indexOf('_segundavisita' == -1) && dataCookie + 2629740000 - agora > 0){
    // segunda visita e caso o cookie esteja dentro de 1 mês de validade
    document.cookie = document.cookie + ' _segundavisita=true;';
    // corre aqui o código da segunda visita
}
```

**Nota:** `2629740000` é 1 mês em milisegundos