# Gravar cookie e ler seu valor ao aceder ao web site para verificar se expirado

Tags: javascript, cookies

Eu preciso fazer um *script* em JavaScript que siga a seguinte lógica:

1. Grave um *cookie* com um `id`, que vai de 1 a 3. Juntamente com o cookie, o dia/horario OU eu quero que ele expire em 8 horas.
2. O usuário, toda vez que entrar no site, deverá ler esse cookie.

   Se ele estiver com o tempo expirado, deverá ler qual `id` parou (1, 2 ou 3), deverá somar 1 ao `id` (caso seja 3 voltar pro 1), e porfim, abrir um popup automática com uma URL, que será definida desta maneira:

   - Se for `id` 1, abrir `dominio.com.br/id1`
   - Se for `id` 2, abrir `dominio.com.br/id2`
   - Se for `id` 3, abrir `dominio.com.br/id3`

Comment: Dá uma olhada a esta pergunta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43889/129), é o mesmo problema que queres resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Você deve usar `document.cookie` para criar os cookies conforme a necessidade e o script deve rodar em um servidor (como Apache por exemplo), acesso local (protocolo `file://`) geralmente não funciona com cookies.

> note que alguns navegadores bloqueiam cookies gerados pelo `http://localhost`, para contornar o problema use o endereço `http://127.0.0.1`

Para criar um cookie devemos usar os parâmetros como abaixo:

```
document.cookie="chave=valor; expires=DATA PARA EXPIRAR; path=CAMINHO";
```

Note que talvez ao invés de cookies você pode usar `localStorage` e `sessionStorage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Por exemplo com `sessionStorage`:

```
// Salva dados na sessão
sessionStorage.setItem("username", "John");

// Pega os dados
alert( "username = " + sessionStorage.getItem("username"));
```

Por exemplo com `localStorage`:

```
// Salva dados na sessão
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");

// Pega os dados
alert( "username = " + localStorage.getItem("username"));
```

Mas como a questão sobre cookies, irei mostrar um exemplo com tal, iremos precisar de dois métodos para isso:

```
function getCookie(k) {
    var cookies = " " + document.cookie;
    var key = " " + k + "=";
    var start = cookies.indexOf(key);

    if (start === -1) return null;

    var pos = start + key.length;
    var last = cookies.indexOf(";", pos);

    if (last !== -1) return cookies.substring(pos, last);

    return cookies.substring(pos);
}

function setCookie(k, v, expira, path) {
    if (!path) path = "/";

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expira * 1000));

    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v) + "; expires=" + d.toUTCString() + "; path=" + path;
}
```

Para definir o seu cookie de ID, faça isto:

```
if (getCookie(id) === null) {//Se o cookie não existir
   var tempodevida = new Date();
   tempodevida.setTime(tempodevida + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2));

   setCookie("id", "1|" + String(new Date().getTime()), tempodevida);
} else {
   ...
}
```

- A string irá formar algo como `1|1419862250858` é o primeiro valor do ID e o numero longo é o que usaremos para comparar as 8 horas.
- `String(new Date().getTime())` pega o horário que o cookie foi criado
- Está linha `60 * 60 * 24 * 2` é um calculo para você entender e modifica-lo conforme a necessidade, ele diz que o cookie deve expirar em dois dias (não tem haver com as suas 8 horas), pois todo cookie deve ter um limite de vida.

  O 1000 é por que o `Date` trabalha com milesegundos, o primeiro 60 seria segundos, o segundo 60 seria minutos, o 24 é o tanto de horas que temos no dia e o 2 seria dois dias.

  Recomendo que você altere apenas o "2", por exemplo que você quiser que o tempo de vida seja de 15 dias, faça isto: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15`

Agora iremos trabalhar o `else` do exemplo. Para verificar devemos usar `getCookie`:

```
var meuCookie = getCookie("id");
```

ele irá retornar como um destes possíveis valores `1|1419862250858`, `2|1419862250858` e `3|1419862250858` (note que o `1419862250858` é apenas um exemplo de tempo). Devemos "cortar" a string usando `String.split`:

```
meuCookie.split("|");

var id    = parseInt(meuCookie[0]);
var tempo = parseInt(meuCookie[1]);
```

Teremos as variáveis `id`  e `tempo` para compara conforme a sua necessidade, que deve ficar algo como:

> Note que `1000 * 60 * 60 * 8` equivale a 8 horas

```
var tempoAtual = new Date();
tempoAtual.setTime(tempoAtual - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 8));

if (tempo < tempoAtual) {//Se tempo for menor que o limite das 8 horas, então significa que expirou
    id++;
    if (id >= 3) {//Se id for igual a 3 volta para o 1
        id = 1;
    }
}
```

Após isto devemos usar `window.location` para redirecionar, seria algo como:

```
window.location = "http://dominio.com/id" + id;
```

O código todo deve ficar assim:

```
function getCookie(k) {
    var cookies = " " + document.cookie;
    var key = " " + k + "=";
    var start = cookies.indexOf(key);

    if (start === -1) return null;

    var pos = start + key.length;
    var last = cookies.indexOf(";", pos);

    if (last !== -1) return cookies.substring(pos, last);

    return cookies.substring(pos);
}

function setCookie(k, v, expira, path) {
    if (!path) path = "/";

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expira * 1000));

    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v) + "; expires=" + d.toUTCString() + "; path=" + path;
}

(function () {
    if (getCookie(id) === null) {
        var tempodevida = new Date();
        tempodevida.setTime(tempodevida + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2));

        setCookie("id", "1|" + String(new Date().getTime()), tempodevida);
    } else {
        var meuCookie = getCookie("id");

        meuCookie.split("|");

        var id    = parseInt(meuCookie[0]);
        var tempo = parseInt(meuCookie[1]);
        var tempoAtual = new Date();
        tempoAtual.setTime(tempoAtual - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 8));
        
        if (tempo < tempoAtual) {
            id++;
            if (id >= 3) {
                id = 1;
            }
        }

        window.location = "http://dominio.com/id" + id;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Não sou Muito bom com isso, mas creio que isso poderá lhe ajudar!

```
<?php

// Determinada um nome pro seu cookie
$cookie = "4567500";

// Verifica se o cookie nao existe
if(!isset($_COOKIE[''.$cookie.''])){

    //Resposta
    echo "Cookie Não existe";

    // Cria um cookie
    $nome = $cookie;
    $valor = "Valor Dentro do Cookie";
    $expira = time() + (8 * 3600);
    setcookie($nome, $valor, $expira);

    //Insere o poup no corpo da pagina
    include_once ("poup.php");

                                    }

elseif(isset($_COOKIE[''.$cookie.'']))
{
    //Resposta do servidor
    echo 'Cookie já existe';

    //Como o cookie existe ele não faz nenhum include
}

?>
```

Esse pequeno código pode ser colocado no começo da pagina, assim sempre que a pessoa entrar no seu site esse código sera processado, e o poup só ira aparecer se ja tiver passado 8hrs ou caso ela nunca tenha entrado

Comment: Isso é PHP, o Fabio pediu em Javascript. :\

Comment: Se for pra usar em um site comum da pra ele usar o php normalmente. Até porque em javascript tudo fica mais complicado e complexo. E é claro isso que eu postei é apenas uma alternativa.